# 404 not found errors for PPAs when I run sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, wine, ppa

```
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/866901/250300 You can remove the PPA, find a new one or wait until it’s upgraded.

Comment: I opened the first link in a browser and looked at supported releases (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/) and bionic (18.04) isn't there.  It currently isn't supported, so you need to use another PPA, or be patient.

Comment: @Melebius has already provided a link that allows for removing the PPA.  Your other option is just comment out the lines in your sources.list* file(s).  Usually when jumping to a later release you'll find yourself using later versions of software, and the need for PPAs reduces - so check you want/need them  (remove, or disable)